# Laravel Way Generator not working with Sublime Text 2

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext2

I'm in Windows XP. I've installed the Way Generators for Laravel and have been trying to get the plugin for Sublime Text 2 to work with them. When I'm testing it by trying to generate a "resource" in Sublime I am getting the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\generate.py", line 59, in call_artisan
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
  File ".\subprocess.py", line 842, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

There's a few people having this problem as seen in the comments here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/pro-workflow-in-laravel-and-sublime-text/

But I have tried loads of different ways of setting the path in the package settings as per the feedback from other people who have had some success but I'm not getting anywhere. Currently I've got this:

```
"php_path": "G:/My Documents/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/php.exe"
```

Additional information: I can run "php" and "artisan" from the command line, so assume the PATH is set correctly. Running the command:

```
php -i
```

from the command line reported that path above as being the location of php.exe

I wonder if having spaces in my php_path setting for Sublime is what is causing the problem? I would be so grateful if someone can help me get up and running with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was:

**Restart Sublime Text after you've applied the setting.**

School boy error (hangs head). So the setting I had in the question was working after all.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and fixed it by doing "G:\My Documents\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe". On windows 7 I had to run sublime as administrator to get it to work properly, don't think you have to run as on xp though.

Answer (score 0):

**Or you can try this one** ( this work for me ),

https://github.com/gnarula/sublime-laravelgenerator/issues/30

**Note** : **remember** always restart sublime everytime you do the change with settings.